# Copying installed packages to new Linux distribution

Tags: python, linux, package

I have been using Python on a Linux desktop for some time and I have installed many packages through pip (some as superuser and others with --user option). Now I am shifting to a newer Linux distribution installed on another partition of same computer.

Is it possible to copy some folder (where pip/python has all installed packages) from older Linux partition to newer Linux partition? This way I will save not only time but also internet bandwidth (for which there is increasing awareness). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont think its possible anyways if you have created a virtual env you may create an requirements file for all dependencies you installed inside your virtual env and then on directly paste your folder via some external means further start development again on new partition directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes, but depending on the changes you've made and where you're coming from and going to, it might take less time to just reinstall them all from your pip list (likely).

```
pip list > piplist #save list of installed packages into 'piplist' file
pip freeze > pipfreeze #save list with versions, which probably won't matter

pip install -r piplist #reinstall packages list (eg: on other system)
pip install -r pipfreeze #reinstall with versioned list
```

If you're shifting to a more recent version of the same distro, you should've just upgraded instead.

If your distro breaks every time you upgrade, you should find another distro.

Comment: Can I transfer this folder: .local/lib/python3.5/site-packages ? It is 2.2Gb folder.

Comment: @mso It's just not worth it. Save the list of packages instead (edited answer to include explicit commands), and reinstall the packages from that list on any subsequent installation. It would've been worth copying your entire installation to new hardware if that were the scenario you were encountering, but it's not really worthwhile to copy this small portion & have to worry about the potential incompatibilities with a new system. Generally, there's no need to back up or preserve software that's easily sourced from online and that you've not modified whatsoever—a new copy will be just as good.

Comment: Ok. It should be `pip install -r pipfreeze` in last statement and not `pip install -r freeze`

Comment: Yes indeed. Fixed.